# Switch the visualization order of traces on Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

is there a way to switch the order of traces while the graph is showing?

example code:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

I'd like to show trace 1, trace2 and vice versa.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try data = [trace2, trace1]

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I need to switch the order of the traces "live", while the graph is running.

Comment: Look into dashboards: https://dashboards.ly/